# Do I have to pay for Minecraft on PS4 if I already own the PC version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I bought Minecraft some time ago on PC. Now I see it's available on the PS Store for PS4, but I seem to have to pay 20 € to get it. Can't I just use my Mojang account to play it on the PS4?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even if you have it for PC, you still need to buy it for the PS4.

The PS4 edition (and other console editions) is different from the PC edition and therefore needs to be bought separately.

If you already have the PS3 edition, the PS4 edition is discounted (see - [Where can I buy Minecraft](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325947-where-can-i-buy-minecraft-))

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have bought it on PC you cannot use your Mojang account to buy it because I think that the PS4 version is not owned by Mojang so you can not use your other account and will have to pay the 20 euros.