# Can I sync minecraft for PlayStation 4, with minecraft PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I started playing on Playstation 4. I created my home and many other things. I do not want to do it again.

Comment: Related: [Do I have to pay for Minecraft on PS4 if I already own the PC version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/186679/4797) | [With Minecraft Windows 10 Edition, do I get a Mojang Account? Power of desktop Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/230826/4797) | [Minecraft on PC and Wii U](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/249775/4797)

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot. Each Minecraft version is isolated in its system. You can't use PS4 saves on PC and the same goes for Xbox One.